# How to convert multiple br tags to single br tag but without spaces

Tags: jquery, html, regex

like if I have br tags in string, but different br tags e.g.

```
<br> or <br/> or <br />
```

there is difference in spaces between "/"
so how to convert all these to uniform br tag i.e. `<br/>` (without any spaces in br and "/")

Comment: You do know that you can search and replace them in almost every code editor? :)

Comment: but i want to do it in php or jquery using regex
and im not that good at regex :(

Comment: They're all rendered as the same thing in the browser - if you aren't fixing it in the source code there's no reason to worry about them in jQuery.

Comment: By the way, when you get three answers and don't mark any of them as accepted or even comment on them it makes me far less likely to look at any of your future questions.

Comment: @HeadCode dont get me wrong, I am still trying all these solutions.
Also looking for something which will fix this in PHP as well

Comment: @rijndael  OK, fair enough.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are regex to convert the br tags :)

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/3Ldqhuae/

```
var str = $("#content").html(), 
    regex = '#(<br */?>\s*)+#i';

$("#content").html( str.replace( regex , '<br />') );
```

Comment: Tried it... works right for me :) thank you very much for your help

Comment: Glad that I could help. You can now accept the answer so the question can be closed :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var mystring = "<br> or <br/> or <br /> <br> or <br/> or <br />";
var mystring2 = mystring.replace(/<br>/g, "<br/>").replace(/<br \/>/g, "<br/>");
```

Or even better:

```
var mystring2 = mystring.replace(/<br *\/*>/g, "<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 var test= "<br> or <br/> or <br />";
 alert(test);
 var testa = test.split("/");

 $.each(testa,function(i,v){
  testa[i] = $.trim(testa[i]);
 });

 alert(testa.join("/"));
```